# Fastest way to create Dictionary from pyspark DF

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snappydata

I'm using Snappydata with pyspark to run my sql queries and convert the output DF into a dictionary to bulk insert it into mongo.
I've gone through many similar quertions to test the convertion of a spark DF to Dictionary.

Currently I'm using `map(lambda row: row.asDict(), x.collect())` this method to convert my **bulk** DF to dictionary. And it is taking 2-3sec for 10K records.

I've stated below how I impliment my idea:

```
x = snappySession.sql("select * from test")
df = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), x.collect())
db.collection.insert_many(df)
```

Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `foreachPartition`:

```
(snappySession
    .sql("select * from test")
    .foreachPartition(insert_to_mongo))
```

where `insert_to_mongo`:

```
def insert_to_mongo(rows):
    client  = ...
    db = ...
    db.collection.insert_many((row.asDict() for row in rows))
```

Comment: did you check or run the code?. it is giving me error `AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'asDict'`

Answer (score 0):

I would look into whether you can directly write to Mongo from Spark, as that will be the best method.

Failing that, you can use this method:

```
x = snappySession.sql("select * from test")
dictionary_rdd = x.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict())

for d in dictionary_rdd.toLocalIterator():
    db.collection.insert_many(d)
```

This will create all the dictionaries in Spark in a distributed manner. The rows will returned to the driver and inserted into Mongo one row at a time so that you don't run out of memory.

Comment: I'm aware of the sending DF directly to mongoDB. From the given [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/) there is not db authentication. This is why i've opted this way.

Comment: Thank you@Anake but its taking nearly 12-15sec. Are there any other ways you suggest?